# How do I get the mouse position on click when it is outside of the component?

Tags: java, click, mouse, mouse-position

I'm writing a small application in Java that will click ten different locations on my screen each minute for 10 minutes. But before doing the clicking I want to choose the locations it will click by clicking on the screen and storing the x & y coordinates in an arraylist.

I have read that I can get it by using MouseInfo however I want to get the coordinates when the mouse is clicked (which may not include being on the component). So how does one do this?

Will I have to create a see through component that takes up the entire screen and get the coordinates that way? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just make a translucent window the size of the screen (which is barely visible) and collected the mouse positions that way. It seemed to work, but I was hoping that I wouldn't have to paint an extra component.

Summarized (for those that care):

- Make translucent window
- User is able to see through the window and can click where one wants
- Mouse coordinates are collected
- Window is discarded

So far this seems to be my best option, unless someone else mentions one shortly :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one...

1. Use *MouseMoved* event to get the mouse position.
2. Plot the *Rectangle* in the window or your component, using the *Rectangle* class and  store the values.
3. In the *MouseClicked* event, get the values of x and y from the mouse moved event and compare with your rectangle array.
4. If the values are between the range the perform the action. (Sorry for the grammer mistakes.)

Ex: code
mousemoved Event:

```
x=event.getX();
y=event.getY();
```

mouseclicked Event:

```
// use Event object e or event to get value of 
x=event.getX();
y=event.getY();

// this is more easy than the mousemoved event..
for(...) {
    if(x > rectangle[i].getMin && rectangle[i].getMax < x
             && y > rectangle[i].getMin && rectangle[i].getMax < y)
    {
        // your action..
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: For the MouseEvents to work wouldn't they need to be within the component? If this is correct, what happens when I want the values outside of the component?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion however I went with the route I was hoping to avoid

Comment: Can u post a solution of Your's Question